# i was sending tax year end statements. While trying to send several at a time, the system crashed, and entered errors in all donations

Tags: receipts

i was trying to send year end tax receipts to all of our donors. I tried to send about 4 at the same time. The system crashed. Then when it came back up I was surprised to see ALL donations for the year have a "thank you sent" date of 1/18/24. However, they weren't actually sent. Worse, it now won't let me send by donor- so every single donation has to be receipted separately- that means LOTs of work and some people getting over 50 emails!.
Help!

Comment: Welcome Richele! I'm sorry to hear about your issue.  Could you please clarify by editing your question: Are you sending tax receipts from the "Find Contributions" screen? Are you using an extension like CDN Tax Receipts? Do you have an error message from the crash you can share? When you say it "won't let you send by donor", can you say more about that - is there an error message?